# ^A (CTRL + A) no cliente telnet

Tags: python, telnet

Estou fazendo um cliente telnet em python e preciso enviar um código pra outra maquina porem o código precisa de botar um <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (CODIGO) mas quando eu coloco `^A` (codigo) não funciona, heeelp me

```
serv = raw_input("[+] SERVER: ")
port = raw_input("[+] PORT: ")
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(serv, port)
mess = ("^AXXXX")
tn.write(mess)
out=tn.read_all()
print(out)
tn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> é o byte 1. Você pode testar da seguinte forma:

```
import sys
print(sys.stdin.readline())
```

Rode e digite <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> e <kbd>Enter</kbd>, o resultado:

```
'\x01\n'
```

portanto para enviá-lo basta enviar esse caracter:

```
mess = "\x01XXXX"
```

ou

```
mess = chr(1) + "XXXX"
```